# ComboPooledDataSource -com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78 cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm trying to use the C3P0 connection pool (com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar), but I'm receiving this error when trying to load an object holding a Clob (Oracle database):

- $Proxy78 cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB

Does anyone know how to solve this?

full stack trace is as below

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the
>   following failure: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78 cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB
>                   at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
>                   at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
>                   at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62)
>                   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.handleThrowable(NewPooledConnection.java:432)
>                   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setClob(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:535)
>                   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$2$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:70)
>                   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$1$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:56)
>                   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
>                   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
>                   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
>                   at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:340)
>                   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
>                   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2559)
>                   ... 71 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78 cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB
>                   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setClob(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6559)
>                   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setClob(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:158)
>                   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setClob(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:521)
>                   ... 79 more

Answer (score 0):

So, this is an odd one. c3p0 doesn't Proxy CLOBs. Somehow the CLOB that you've gotten has been wrapped behind a Java standard dynamic proxy. You'll need to figure out how that happened. Where did your proxied CLOB object come from?

It looks as though hibernate sometimes proxies CLOBs, see [ClobProxy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/ClobProxy.html). Maybe this is why you have a proxy rather than the sort of CLOB your driver expects?